# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (//) at position 0 (/): Unexpected character

Tags: php, mysql, rest

Could not pass date to MySQL using php POST method. Got the error as given in the title.
Here is my code.

```
<code>
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$dd = substr($dob,0,2)."/";
$mm = substr($dob,3,2)."/";
$yyyy = substr($dob,6,4);
$fd = $yyyy.$mm.$dd;
$date = new DateTime($fd);
$formDateConverted = $date->format('Y-m-d');
<code>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I cannot see where your code invokes MySQL. Please provide the relevant section(s) of your PHP or other code so that the community can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are getting data ? Your `substr()` must be returning empty strings.

You are adding a slash to your day and month and putting them back together in the wrong order. Just run your code with a fixed string:

```
$dob = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
$dd = substr($dob,0,2)."/";
$mm = substr($dob,3,2)."/";
$yyyy = substr($dob,6,4);
$fd = $yyyy.$mm.$dd;

var_dump($fd);
```

Result:

```
string(10) "yyyymm/dd/"
```

To me, `$dob` is clearly empty, as all three variables resulting from the `substr()` are as well, except for the slashes you add back, which is what you get on the error. Run the code again with an empty variable and you'll get: `string(2) "//"`.

Once you fix your `$dob` issue, you can use the `DateTime` class directly as suggested by Chayan:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dob);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Still getting the error. I am sharing the file...please have a look. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZS04t8NU5Sj_HPnve5qoxJCXta82YXN-

Comment: @Mukhtar Your `$fd` assignment is still wrong because of your `substr` length. This time you get: `string(10) "m/yy//m/dd"` and you **don't need** to do it. Please see my last code sample.

Comment: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dob);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');     Using these code sample gives this error "Call to a member function format() on boolean"

Comment: @Mukhtar That's because `createFromFormat` cannot parse your date with the specified format and returns `false`. Can you post a dump of your `$dob` content?

Comment: sharing the files. Please have a look. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QUcmBV-o44GYSDoRGaG7sc3xjfDBRQP-

Comment: But that's an API call from an external application. I need the value reaching **your** actual app.

Comment: I think you have understood the problem well. Please give me a solution. I am stuck in this DateTime error.

Comment: I am testing it in the Postman application only. I am yet to deploy it. I think the value received from the actual app will be in dd/mm/yyyy format only.

Comment: All your variables come from the `$request_data` array. All but your `$dob` that is accessing `$response_data`. So your variable is empty, right ?

Comment: Yes.. That was a typo. I have changed that to $request_data. But still getting the same error. Call to a member function format() on boolean.

Comment: @Mukhtar can you please post a `var_dump($dob)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. It's working now. The problem was with that typo $response_data., after changing it to $request_data it is working fine. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

By default PHP can't parse date having '/' in it. Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function.

```
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $fd);
 echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: @Mukhtar He's also getting an empty `$dob` variable in there. That's what you should pass to your `createFromFormat()` with the proper format string instead of using that `$fd` thing (how it is pieced together is wrong too)

Comment: $dob contains the date received from the form, and it is in the format dd/mm/yyyy. Since date is stored in yyyy-mm-dd format in MySQL, I tried to rearrange the date ($dob) in reverse order, by concatenating the three parts, namely $yyyy,$mm, and $dd and stored it in $fd. But while storing the the data it gives the error as given in the title of this post.